# Why does this regex match too much? (Doesn't stop at slash)

Tags: php, regex

This code outputs the `$captured` array, but `$captured[1]` contains `bar/this` rather than my expected `bar`. What's missing in my regex to stop from returning more than `bar`?

```
<?php

    $pattern = '/foo/:any/';
    $subject = '/foo/bar/this/that';

    $pattern = str_replace(':any', '(.+)', $pattern);
    $pattern = str_replace(':num', '([0-9]+)', $pattern);
    $pattern = str_replace(':alpha', '([A-Za-z]+)', $pattern);

    echo '<pre>';

    $pattern = '#^' . $pattern . '#';
    preg_match($pattern, $subject, $captured);

    print_r($captured);
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: I fail to see how your regex pattern could work at all. The string replacements will turn it into `/foo/(.+)/`, and now you've got a `/` pattern delimiter INSIDE your pattern without being escaped. At mininum it should look like `/foo\/(.+)/` to make it a valid regex.

Comment: Ah sorry I also had `$pattern = '#^' . $pattern . '#';` in there, forgot to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [non-greedy modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) to make the `+` match as *few* characters as possible instead of as *many* as possible:

```
$pattern = str_replace(':any', '(.+?)', $pattern);
                                   ^
```

You probably also want to add [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) round your regular expression and anchor it to the start of the string:

```
$pattern = '#^/foo/:any/#';
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as `$pattern = str_replace(':any', '(.*)', $pattern);
`

Comment: @Walkerneo: No. The asterisk is still greedy (but it allows zero repetitions whereas `+` needs at least one).

Comment: @Walkerneo no. `+` is a greedy search and will take all found characters until the last `/` is found. The `?` makes the search non-greedy, and stops at the first occurence of `/`.

Comment: @Mark: Isn't it strange that he didn't get `bar/this/that` in `$captured[1]`?

Comment: @TimPietzcker no, his `$subject` doesn't end in a `/`, so it wouldn't match the last word.

Comment: @BrianGraham: But the slashes in his pattern are taken as delimiters. Actually, now that I'm looking at it, he should be getting an "invalid mode modifier" error because `foo` would be his pattern and `(.+)/` would be interpreted as mode modifiers...Ah, now he's commented his question explaining what he left out of the question...

Answer (score 1):

The dot is greedy and matches as many characters as possible. Either make it lazy:

```
$pattern = str_replace(':any', '(.+?)', $pattern);
```

or keep it from matching slashes:

```
$pattern = str_replace(':any', '([^\/]+)', $pattern);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is rather confusing and misleading and if run it, it outputs a warning:

> Warning: preg_match(): Unknown modifier '(' in php shell code on line 1

What I think is wrong is:

```
$pattern = '/foo/:any/';
#should be
$pattern = '/foo\/:any/';
```

because you need to escape a forward slash in regexp.

After this is fixed the script returns:

```
(
  [0] => foo/bar/this/that
  [1] => bar/this/that
)
```

Which is an expected result. As you match `foo/` and everything afterwards with `(.*)`. If you want to match anything until the next forward slash you have some possibilities:

```
$pattern = '/foo/(.*?)/'     #non greedy
$pattern = '/foo/([^\/]*)/'  #not matching any forward slash
$pattern = '@foo/:any/@'     #or using different start and end markers, e.g. @
```

Comment: I had different delimiters that I forgot to include in the original post (now edited) like so: `$pattern = '#^' . $pattern . '#';`, that way I wouldn't have to escape forward slashes.