# PHP Regex: Extract lucky and charms from <a>lucky <b>charms</b></a>

Tags: php, expression

Reqex Question:
Extract words

```
lucky
charms
```

from string:

```
<a>lucky <b>charms</b></a>
```

My attempt:

```
preg_match_all("/<(.*)>(.*)<\/(.*)>+/is", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <a>lucky <b>charms</b></a>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a>lucky <b>charms</b
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a
        )

)
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Regex too greedy? Make it less greedy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this regex match too much? (Doesn't stop at slash)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8100746/why-does-this-regex-match-too-much-doesnt-stop-at-slash)

Comment: Have you tried using `strip_tags()`?

Comment: @Mathieu Imbert I don't want to strip tags. Because I will be replacing lucky and charms later on.. and still need the tags

Comment: You could always make a copy of it, then use strip tags on the copy.  Then you'd get your lucky charms, but not lose your original tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about everything in between a closing tag and the next opening tag

```
preg_match_all("/\>([^\<]+)\</is", $text, $matches);
```

Then the matches you want are in `$matches[1]`

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => >lucky <
            [1] => >charms<
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => lucky 
            [1] => charms
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you always have that structure, you can use:

```
preg_match("#<(.*?)>(.*?)<(.*?)>(.*?)</\\3></\\1>#is", '<a>lucky <b>charms</b></a>', $matches);
```

Which `$matches` contains:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(26) "lucky charms"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "a"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "lucky "
  [3]=>
  string(1) "b"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "charms"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not suitable, because * is gready use ? to make * non-gready or change your regex in something like this

```
<([^>]+)>(.*?)</\1>
```